# Is a there any convex function where calculating its conjugate is costly or not possible?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

In some optimization problems we have convex losses like convex lp-norms etc. And most of the cases calculating the convex conjugate is possible and does not cost much than calculating the loss function itself.

I wanted to ask if there is any convex loss function where calculating its conjugate is costly or not possible?

Comment: Are you looking for loss functions in machine learning specifically or whatever types of functions?

Comment: It could be in machine learning or in any other fields. Loss functions like lp norms, huber, hinge, logistic loss etc. But I wanted to know if there is a convex loss function where calculating its conjugate is costly. It would be very helpful for me if I can find a loss function such that :).

Comment: @displayname as per my answer, try calculating the conjugate of a sum, e.g. $\|\cdot\|_p+H$ where $H$ is the hinge loss.

Comment: @Zim Thank you very much Zim. 
Is there an application of lp + hinge loss in any fields (or paper)?

Comment: @displayname I'm not sure about that particular sum, but I'd be shocked if there wasn't a paper using hinge loss to regularize e.g. $\|A\cdot-b\|_p$. However, my point is that the conjugate of a sum is not always easy to compute, so I'm sure you can find the sum of two functions *somewhere*! Folks come up with all sorts of wacky regularizers out there.

Comment: @displayname If you want a concrete example, what is the conjugate of the LASSO objective function $\|A\cdot-b\|_p+\|\cdot\|_1$?

Comment: @Zim I need only a convex loss function rather than whole objective. So, using hinge loss to regularize a convex function does not work in my case. However, conjugate of sum seems interesting, I dont know if there is any paper regularizes a function with a loss function which is a sum, but worth to check (like elastic net except instead of having two regularizers and one loss, having two losses and one regularizer).

Comment: @displayname Then the title of your question should have stated that you specifically need a loss function. Not to mention, the difference between "loss" and "regularizer" is not incredibly well-defined...

Answer (score 0):

Even if you know the conjugate of $f$ and $g$, the conjugate of $f+g$ may not be tractable.

In particular, let $f$ and $g$ be convex, proper, lower-semicontinuous functions on a real Hilbert space $X$. Then The conjugate of a sum of functions is the infimal convolution of their conjugates (This result appears in Bauschke & Combettes' book, volume 2, e.g. pp. 247):

$$(f+g)^*(x)=\inf_{\substack{(z,y)\in X \\ z+y=x}}f^*(z)+g^*(y)$$

The expression on the righthand side (called the "infimal convolution of $f^*$ and $g^*$") can only sometimes be expressed in closed-form. One instance is the Moreau envelope, but in general this is not possible.

I have heard, however, that there are efficient methods to numerically *approximate* a conjugate evaluation.